# Open sqlite database multiple times or single time?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am newbie with Swift, learning working with SQlite, I wonder where to open database?

a) multiple times, on each ViewController I need to use

b) open once and keep it as instance for whole application?
-how to do it?

In theory, the solution a, means that I will load database to memory every time I want to use it. Maybe I am wrong but it's ugly.

Can I get some clarification from experienced swift developers?

I have such code from tutorial, but it's used on ViewController

```swift
//the database file
       let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
           .appendingPathComponent("HeroesDatabase.sqlite")

       //opening the database
       if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
           print("error opening database")
       }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No SQLite code should be in any view controller. You should write a class that encapsulates all reading and writing of data from/to the database. Then your other classes (such as view controllers) request and submit data to that class as needed.

In other words, a single database class represents your data and its persistence. No other code needs to know you are even using SQLite.

As for your initial question, there is nothing wrong with keeping a single database connection open for the lifetime of your app. That's what I do. And having it all in one class makes it simple. The database isn't "in memory" just because it's open. But it really depends on how heavy your database access is. In my app, every screen and every tap results in database access. So I have one open connection and make good use of prepared statements. But if you only have occasional database access, opening, querying, and closing each time won't be a problem. I also have a lot of overhead when opening my database. I install lots of custom functions and other setup. Doing that for every query would be painful.